# Can I read InputStream through a BufferedImage?

Tags: java, image, inputstream, bufferedimage, javax.imageio

```
InputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(b);
BufferedImage bImageFromConvert = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
Graphics g = bImageFromConvert.createGraphics();
g = cvrimg.getGraphics();
g.drawImage(bImageFromConvert, width, height, null);
ImageIO.write(bImageFromConvert, "png", new File("D:\\new.png"));
```

I am getting th following exception:
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: im == null!`

What should I do ?

**This is the sample code:**

```
BufferedImage cvrimg = ImageIO.read(file);
int height = cvrimg.getHeight();
int width = cvrimg.getWidth();
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(new_img, "jpg", baos);
baos.flush();
byte[] imageInByte = baos.toByteArray();
byte[] b = new byte[imageInByte.length];
b[i] = fromUnsignedInt(b2);
InputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(b);
BufferedImage bImageFromConvert = new BufferedImage(width,height,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

// int inBytes = bais.available();

Graphics g = bImageFromConvert.createGraphics();
g = cvrimg.getGraphics();
g.drawImage(bImageFromConvert, width, height, null);
bImageFromConvert=ImageIO.read(bais);
ImageIO.write(bImageFromConvert, "png", new File("D:\\new.png"));
```

Comment: There is no "im" variable in the code you sent us. The answer lies somewhere else.

Comment: "im" is the 1st parameter of ImageIO.write().

Comment: This is in the ImageIO library.

`public static boolean write(RenderedImage im,
                                String formatName,
                                ImageOutputStream output) throws IOException {
        if (im == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("im == null!");
        }`

Comment: Well you have figured out the important piece of code then. Now just put a debugger on the first line and check which variables are null.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: the thing is none of the values are null.

"b" returns `[B@34fbb7cb`

"bais" returns `java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@79df8b99`

"bImageFromConvert" returns `BufferedImage@43462851: type = 1 DirectColorModel: rmask=ff0000 gmask=ff00 bmask=ff amask=0 IntegerInterleavedRaster: width = 79 height = 22 #Bands = 3 xOff = 0 yOff = 0 dataOffset[0] 0`

Comment: i want to know why am i not able to write the image file.

Comment: *"i want to know why am i not able to write the image file."*  I (and many others) could probably tell you within 10 minutes of seeing an SSCCE.

Comment: @AndrewThompson - i post the SSCCE already..!!

Comment: No you didn't.  An SSCCE is not code snippets.  Please read the article again and if there is anything you do not understand, ask me.  I should be able to explain, ..since I wrote it.  ;)

Answer (score 1):

You are getting exception because you didn't read the input stream. Use

```
BufferedImage im = ImageIO.read(bais);
```

A simple converter from your code that reads a `jpg` file and writes to `png` file.

```
BufferedImage cvrimg = ImageIO.read(new File("/path/to/images/old.jpg"));
int height = cvrimg.getHeight();
int width = cvrimg.getWidth();
BufferedImage bImageFromConvert = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
Graphics2D g = bImageFromConvert.createGraphics();
g.drawRenderedImage(cvrimg, null);
ImageIO.write(bImageFromConvert, "png", new File("/path/to/images/new.png"));
```

Comment: @VivekParekh Look at the example I've made what you wanted to achieve.

Comment: That is not a problem .. even when i read a png file and try to write the it in a new png file... i get the value im == null.

im is the parameter that is passed by the ImageIO.write(RenderedImage im, ...,...)

Comment: @VivekParekh You should write the image that you has drawn, not that you have created.